# How do i detect when android device screen is about to timeout or "Lock"?

Tags: android

I have an android application that needs to detect when the screen is going to lock.
is it possible to discover how long the screen will stay "UnLocked" for?

Comment: You can subscribe to receiving a broadcast with action [ACTION_SCREEN_OFF](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) but it sends after the screen turns off.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to register a broadcast reciever.Your system will send a brodcast when device is going to sleep. Put the following code wherever desired:

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
  //check if the broadcast is our desired one
  if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF))
//here define your method to be executed when screen is going to sleep

}};
```

you will need to register your receiver:

```
    IntentFilter regFilter = new IntentFilter();
// get device sleep evernt
regFilter .addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
registerReceiver(receiver, regFilter );
```

[ACTION_SCREEN_OFF](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) is sent after the screen turns off and [ACTION_SCREEN_ON](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_ON) is sent after the screen turns on.

UPDATE:

1.Method 1: As far as i know, you can not setup a listener before ur device goes to sleep.There is no such listener inside PowerManager. A solution which comes to my mind is to get the [device time out from the settings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT) and then setup a count down timer in your app. The countdown should be reset every time user touches screen. This way you may guess the time when the device goes to sleep and then setup a wakelock before the device goes to sleep and run your desired code and after that,disable the wakelock and the put the device to sleep.

2.Method 2: inPause() method of your activity is called when your device goes to sleep. You might be able to do some code there.Just a thought.

Comment: afterburner - thanks for this, it "almost" fits my requirements, i need to know when its going to lock, e.g. as its "running out of time" NOT when its "RUN out of time". the receiver approach will be to late for my requirements. i need a "countdown" to screen locking. android must have an expiry timer (or something equivalent) that knows when to lock the screen or the time out duration has expired. can i get access to that timer?

Comment: @user423199 i get what you really wanna do and sadly i am not aware of any clean approaches. I updated the answer. Hope it helps somehow.

Comment: i have been searching throgh the android source code for a solution to my requirements.
i have found this class NetworkPolicyManagerService has a private action intent called "com.android.server.net.action.SNOOZE_WARNING"
which sounds like it could be just what i need to listen for. Am i going to be able to use this? will i need to have MANAGE_NETWORK_POLICY
permission in my manifest?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use "Wakelock"..
try this code

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
     wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "whatever");wl.acquire();
```

And don't forget to take permission in your menifest
"android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"
and write wl.release() in your pouse() method..