# How to detect when the screen will turn off?

Tags: android, wakelock

Is it possible to detect when screen will turn off and catch it? I want to set timer for 15 seconds in global settings of Android. I am trying to find some information how to catch wake-lock mode.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947126/how-do-i-detect-when-android-device-screen-is-about-to-timeout-or-lock

Comment: Take a look at [Keeping the Device Awake](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#screen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just register your app for the actions `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` and `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON` and do what you want when these events are broadcasted.

Create a dedicated `BroadcastReceiver` class (and add it to the manifest) or register a `BroadcastReceiver` at runtime.

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11350278/56285), you cannot declare `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` and `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` in AndroidManifest; you need to do it in code

Comment: How does this detect lock-screen on/off?

Comment: @Jonik Thanks! it was like a quest. From your link I went Stack, then to another comment, then to another site :) Finally: https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/